# HTTP Redirect in asp.net along with Tridion

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I have implemented URL redirection in one of application in asp.net and Tridion. Whenever I add any new redirect URL, I have to restart the application pool to reflect the changes because I am maintaining these redirect URLs in a configuration file which is referenced in the web.config file through configSource attribute as below –

```
    <httpRedirect configSource="HttpRedirect.config" />
```

Could anybody suggest me the way to get changes reflected immediately without restarting app pool?
Is there any way to get the app pool restarted automatically  after any new change in the HttpRedirect.config   file?

NOTE – I would not want to merge HttpRedirect.config  file in the web.config due to being too large list of URLs.

Though question is fairly related to the asp.net technology. Since I know a lot of member in Tridion using asp.net can help me here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

You could do the redirection manually and pull the URL from a database table.

This would mean the redirection could be changed on the fly with a simple database update which would not need the app pool to be restarted.

Comment: @GlenH7 noted and updated.

Answer (score 8):

I have successfully used [UrlRewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/) in the past with a similar configuration as yours - a component in Tridion with the url mappings, and at publish time I would generate the required configuration file for this module.

I didn't have to restart the app pool for this to take effect, it was immediate.

Comment: Thanks Nuno , had you used <httpRedirect /> or <rewrite /> for this ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I use an open source module (UrlRewrite.Net) that does the redirects itself. In the web.config I added a section that points the configuration to the separate file, and then the module kicks in when urls are requested that match the urls patterns as defined by my rules...

Answer (score 6):

Frankly I do not have any experience on this particular stuff so cannot say anything about why it is working with Nuno and not with you. May be you both are maintaining  the cache differently in your application.

But keeping your concern in to mind I can suggest you a work around here.

As I know that changes to configuration setting in the web.config file cause the application domain to restart automatically and if you are doing any change in the external config file referenced in to web.config through the configSource attribute application domain will not get restarted automatically. Here is a simple work around -

**“Just publish your web.config file  also along with HttpRedirect.config”.**

By doing so your application domain will get restarted.
You can do it through the Tridion code or manually

Comment: This seems like the most simple solution but there may be considerations around caching etc.

Comment: Yes ,I agree with you Rob that's why I said it a workaround. if someone covered a long way with an implementation , he can go with this workaround :-)

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider using a 'Custom Rewrite Provider' with the standard 'URL Rewrite' module.  This would allow you to use an external file (published from Tridion) to manage the URLs.  There are further details on this [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module).

**There is example code, linked to from that page, for "Storing of the rewrite or redirect mappings in a text file".**  You could publish these text files from Tridion.  I am fairly sure from memory that the App Pool does not need to be recycled to pick up changes to the published files.

Answer (score 2):

Not an ideal approach (another work-around), but if the httpredirect.config file is kept in the *bin* directory, your application pool will automatically restart whenever the file is updated. Any file change in the *bin* folder causes the application to restart.

This is not ideal for numerous reasons, performance being one. Users visiting during the restart will experience a slower "experience" as the website spins up and cache's are repopulated etc...